# How to run step (sequential) regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, sequential

I'd like to run a sequential regression

```
Step1: y ~ a + b + c

Step2: y ~ a + b + c + a:b + a:c + b:c

Step3: y ~ a + b + c + a:b + a:c + b:c + a:b:c
```

I tried

```
firstModel  = lm(y ~ a + b + c, data=data1)

secondModel = lm(y ~ a + b + c + a:b + a:c + b:c, data=data1) 

fullModel  =  lm(y ~ a + b + c + a:b + a:c + b:c + a:b:c, data=data1) 

scope1 = list(firstModel, secondModel, fullModel)

step1 = step(firstModel, scope = scope1, data=data1, direction="forward")
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a + b + c + a:c, data = data1)
```

In this result, I don't see the 3 models I specified. Why is that?
Is there a way to "force" R to calculate the regression for the 3 models?

Comment: `do.call(AIC, scope1)`? It's unclear what your issue is.

Comment: You have already fit all three models.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: what I'm trying to do is force R to check sequentially these 3 models and see which one of them is best (in SPSS you'd call them blocks, and you'd run the analysis using an ENTER parameter in a regression analysis). The problem here, with this R script, is that R doesn't test these 3 blocks, but rather provides a result of a fourth one, namely, a+b+c+a:c